# jQuery Mobile graphic different on mobile devices than when viewed on a desktop browser

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a `jQuery Mobile` radio button set that when viewed on a desktop browser displays a gray-filled dot for inactive selections and a red-filled dot with a white center for the active selection.

However, when I view the page in a mobile device (either `iOS` or `Android)`, I get nothing for the inactive selections and a curious new graphic for the active selection. The new graphic is a red dot but has three white bars stacked vertically upon one another and to the right side of the dot.

Normally I wouldn't really care but this graphic looks like it could be a corporate logo or something and therefore is somewhat distracting. Plus the missing gray dots for inactive selections is annoying. Anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: Using the site a bit will grant you enough privileges to upload a pic soon.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately this is one of those questions where an image would go a long way toward resolving the problem.

Comment: I removed the complain as it does not add value to the question.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was in case anyone else should have the same issue. There is a CSS Media rule that sets a background image sprite and its positioning. It was displaying one of the other icon options instead of the radio button icon. Adjusted that and now it displays fine.